# How can I make a button a loading button as long as the function is executed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bulma

**Initial situation**

- I have several functions within an app script
- The functions are started via a sidebar - by clicking on different
  buttons
- I have created the sidebar with [Bulma CSS](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/#states)

**Problem**

When starting the function via the sidebar, no message is shown that the function has been started - unlike when starting the function directly or via a custom menu.

This can confuse the user because he clicks and nothing happens at first.

I don't know if this is generally the case with a sidebar, that no indication of the executing function is displayed, or if this has something to do with the event that triggers the function:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.myFunction()" class="button is-link"></button>
```

**My idea**

Bulma CSS also has a loading button: `<button class="button is-loading">Loading</button>`

My idea is that when a button is clicked and the function starts, that the button then becomes the loading button.
As long as the function is working. When the runtime of the function ends, the loading button should become a normal button again.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script using `withSuccessHandler`?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function myFunction() {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return "ok";
}
```

#### HTML side:

```js
<button onclick="run()" id="button" class="button is-link">button</button>
<script>
function run() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.className = "button is-loading"
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    console.log(e); // Here, you can see the returned value.
    button.className = "button is-link";
  }).myFunction();
}
</script>
```

- In this sample, please load Bulma CSS.
- When the button is clicked, the button is changed to the loading situation of `button is-loading`. When `myFunction` of Google Apps Script is finished, the button is changed to the initial situation of `button is-link`.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Is there a way to use the HTML side for multiple functions? Or do I have to create a separate HTML side for each function and rename it accordingly, e.g. run01, run02 etc.?
P.S. It also works without me adding the Google Apps Script side to the function.

Comment: @user3392296 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new questions of `Is there a way to use the HTML side for multiple functions? Or do I have to create a separate HTML side for each function and rename it accordingly, e.g. run01, run02 etc.?`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. What I mean is, what if I have another function called myFunction02 for example.
Can I integrate this into your script function run(), or do I have to create a new function run02()?

Comment: @user3392296 Thank you for replying. About `What I mean is, what if I have another function called myFunction02 for example. Can I integrate this into your script function run(), or do I have to create a new function run02()?`, I cannot understand this new question. Can I ask you the detail of your new question? I think that my English skill is very poor. So, I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. By correctly understanding your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I try to correctly understand your new question.

Comment: @user3392296 Although I could resolve your question, I cannot understand your new question. I really apologize for my very poor English skill again. And also, I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon. If you want the answer to your new question immediately, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, a lot of users can think of a solution to your new question and you might be able to obtain a solution for your new question. I really apologize for my poor English skill again.